# WinSCP connecting to WinSSHD and executing terminal commands

Tags: windows, winscp

I have a windows server that has WinSSHD installed.

If i configure a user to support "Teminal Access" and then connect using WinSCP i cannot launch a terminal session - has anyone got these to work together and support remote terminal sessions?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use WinSCP? That's for file transfers. Use [PuTTy](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) instead.

Comment: Because it's got amazing scripting support. It is used during Continuous Deployment for our build environment.

Comment: Does PuTTy work? What's your error message?

Comment: Does PuTTy support automated scripting?

Comment: KiTTy provides scripting support (puTTy fork): http://kitty.9bis.com/

This is not the point however. Are you able to login using PuTTy? If login does not work, then scripting won't work neither :)